# Rails solr sunspot 404 and 503 errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sunspot, sunspot-solr

I'm using rails 4. On my local server i made an app https://github.com/alexefremo/daysandnights it working well still.  And solr there working great, But when i'm pulling my app it works well too, but when i'm trying to search with solr i got an error. Different errors. I tried some answers here, on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work. It only writing me different errors. When i.m trying to reindex it (by the way database is empty (no records)) it throws me an error 503:

```
Error - RSolr::Error::Http - 503 Service Unavailable - retrying...
```

in sunspot.yml i got:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    #path: /solr/production
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5

development:
  solr:
    hostname: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    #path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    #path: /solr/test
```

`

On my ip i got:

```
Error 404 - Not Found.

No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
/solr ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.0/solr/solr-webapp/webapp/},/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.0/solr/webapps/solr.war
```

What's the deal? I've been struggling with solr all night long. How it works on my local machine perfectly and doesn't work on my VPS at all?

p.s. i got:

```
rails (4.0.2, 4.0.1)
sunspot (2.1.0)
sunspot_rails (2.1.0)
sunspot_solr (2.1.0)
```

Comment: bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start solved my problem.